# Python Pandas: Rename columns after pivoting

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe that is pivoted. I do not know how to change column names so that I can continue working with the pivoted dataframe in a natural way. Below is a minimal working example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                            'two'],
                    'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})
```

After pivoting with

```
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values=['baz', 'zoo'])
```

the output is:

```
      baz       zoo
bar   A  B  C   A  B  C
foo
one   1  2  3   x  y  z
two   4  5  6   q  w  t
```

What would be the following step to do in order to obtain below output?

```
   A_baz  B_baz  C_baz   A_zoo  B_zoo  C_zoo

one   1    2       3       x      y      z
two   4    5       6       q      w      t
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What `pandas` version is this? I get an error on the `.pivot()` which says `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan - For me in pandas 0.23.4 it working nice.

Comment: Doesn't work with `'0.20.3'` :(

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan - time to upgrade if possible ;)

Comment: @ Vivek Kalyanarangan - I observed the same error with pivot(), however it worked with pivot_table(). My pandas version is 0.22.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `f-string`s with list comprehension:

```
#python 3.6+
df.columns = [f'{j}_{i}' for i, j in df.columns]
#lower python versions
#df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(j, i) for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
    A_baz B_baz C_baz A_zoo B_zoo C_zoo
foo                                    
one     1     2     3     x     y     z
two     4     5     6     q     w     t
```

Or [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with `map` and `join`:

```
df = df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values=['baz', 'zoo']).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
    A_baz B_baz C_baz A_zoo B_zoo C_zoo
foo                                    
one     1     2     3     x     y     z
two     4     5     6     q     w     t
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `names_glue` parameter to reshape the column names:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_wider(
    index = 'foo', 
    names_from = 'bar', 
    values_from = ['baz', 'zoo'], 
    names_glue = "{bar}_{_value}")

   foo A_baz B_baz C_baz A_zoo B_zoo C_zoo
0  one     1     2     3     x     y     z
1  two     4     5     6     q     w     t
```

in the names_glue string template, `_value` serves as a placeholder for values from `values_from`. Anything in the `{}` brackets should either be from `names_from` or `_value` to represent `values_from`.